# When should my website be HTTPS to communicate with facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, http, https, facebook-apps

if I want to connect my website to facebook to achieve the following functionality:

- Login using facebook.
- Posting to some specific owned facebook page.

do I need to use https connection instead of regular http?

P.S: some resources on how could I do it using PHP may make me very thankful.

Comment: AFAIK, no. Because when you incorporate the facebook API, it handles the login process for you.

Comment: The connection is done by facebook using https you don't need to worry about that.. anyway if you can use https everywhere.

Comment: You're not required to use SSL (`https`) unless you're going to **use page tabs or your app is a canvas app**